# How to communicate that an app never sends information to a server?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, security, privacy, credit-cards

If you have an app that never sends any information to any server, what would be the best way to communicate this via the UI?

---

**Background:**

I produce an app that stores data chosen by the user, encrypts it and digitally signs it, and sends it to other users of the app. Users' data never hits my server, not even as ciphertext.

What UX techniques will help users understand that no data is ever sent to my servers?

Comment: So your server doesn't even save encrypted version of the user's data?  What about when user does #3?  Is it Peer to Peer?

Comment: Yes it's P2P.  My server stores nothing. Ever. @junglee It's based on patened encryption that allows for this 3 part privacy to occur.

Comment: Please make this question general enough that the answer could be useful to other readers of this site. As it stands, you're basically asking for suggestions to fix a specific problem that only you have.  I am putting in on hold, but if you improve it to meet the site guidelines, it can be reviewed to re-open.

Comment: This is a great question about building trust with users and communicating back-end details in a way that users can understand. I hope the community is willing to reopen it and allow others to weigh in.

Comment: @LamonteCristo - it seems to me that this is a unique enough scenario (2016) that it needs to be explicitly stated in a variety of places and that an icon should be associated with it. Then - whenever there is an upload link that icon (or perhaps simply the phrase "No Data is sent to XXX servers" is appended to the link.

Comment: @Mayo The problem is the focus on his one app, rather than a statement of a general case which would be applicable to more people.  Most of the question is focused entirely on what his app does, so I view it as being primarily about that.  If it's narrowed down to a general case, I agree that it would be a great question.  I'll try narrow it down, but feel free to improve my edit.

Comment: We've recently treated a similar question on the Security site: [How to communicate security expectations to users in an end-to-end encrypted app](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110629/how-to-communicate-security-expectations-to-users-in-an-end-to-end-encrypted-cha/110630#110630). I could copy/pasta the answer here if the mods find it acceptable to do so across SE sites.

Comment: The take-away is: visualise it if possible, where relevant and when users have available attention to spare (e.g. waiting time on a splash screen as a conversation loads or a file is encrypted, or as a passive / background image on a file sending UI; respect the principle of not wasting user time on secondary stuff) and in ways that don't require active / effortful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your users wish their data to remain utterly private.

Why not simply tell it as it is?

Some form of banner or click box to be ticked during sign-up which specifys "None of your encrypted data stored by us - ever. Guaranteed." or similar.

Answer (score 1):

As YorkshireDave said, give the user this info on signup. Give it simply and to the point. But *also* give them this info at the point at which they're most likely to consider security of their information again while using the app. If there's a Save button or a Send button, try to incorporate this into the UI by visually associating it with that button.

You may even try to rename the button "Save Securely" or "Send Securely" with a little info icon next to it that gives a modal popup with more detail... ideally with a little image that illustrates the encryption and sending process with the fact that no server holds the user's info highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two places where such a message would be useful/important:

1. On the install screen where you have the overview of your application:

   > Your data is encrypted and sent directly to the other users you have selected. At no point is any of your data stored on our servers.
2. On the "Help > About" dialog (should such a dialog exist in your application). You can either re-use the wording from the install screen or go into more details.

Less useful/important would be to include this information on a dialog/screen every time the user sends a message as this would get in the way of the message sending workflow. If "the powers that be" insist on having this, then make it so the user can select a "don't show me this again" option when dismissing the dialog.